# Structure for genericDAO

Tags: java, hibernate

This is a general programming practice question and totally open to modifications if its not clear. I have implemented a customDao instead of using hibernate and other orm tools.

Take a look at its get method:

```
def list(Map map){
    def condition=""
    int count=0
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if(count != 0) condition +=" AND "
        def key=entry.getKey().toLowerCase()
        def value="'"+entry.getValue()+"'"
        condition +=key+" = "+value
        count++
    }
    def SQL="SELECT * FROM  "+entityClass.getSimpleName().toLowerCase()+" WHERE "+condition
    log.debug "........"+SQL
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(SQL)
}
```

generally it takes a `Map` for conditions and returns list we want with the conditions in map.

eg. `customDao.list([parentid:1,name:"blabla"])`

Here I can ask for all database records with parentid=1 and name="blabla"

So far so good?

What if I need to get a list for `parentid!=1`, I mean for now ,I take map conditions for equality but what should I do for inequality or greaterThan or lesserThan conditions.

Long story short I have to get these conditions in receiving parameters of list method.What are the best practices.

Comment: I would recommend reading about Hibernate Criteria Queries - start with http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Comment: brilliant recommendation sir.

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious flaw of your code is that it is vulnerable to SQL injection. Imagine someone were to call it with

```
customDao.list([parentid:"1; drop table student; --"])
```

The resulting SQL would be

```
select * from student where parentid = 1; drop table student; --;
```

You don't want that, right?

This vulnerability is so common that [cartoons exist about it](https://xkcd.com/327/).

In general, I recommend not to reinvent a wheel unless you can improve upon the wheels that already exist. In your case, there are probably better wheels out there, such as [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from being vulnerable to SQL injection like @meriton pointed out, which may be able to be fixed, this approach is probably too generic.

Let's say you wanted to query a table about employees. You will need to specify the parameters you are querying on that are specific to the employee table in your database. You will also need to extract the data out of the resulting list when the query is done. Instead of scattering those employee-related variables/code all over your project, you will probably set up some class that just interacts with the generic dao for employee related queries... in which case you are effectively creating an employee dao. So you will end up with separate, non-generic, daos anyway.

I would suggest using an already established ORM, create a designated DAO for each model in your application, or use some other data access pattern.

Comment: If it's not possible to rework the database design itself, you could just go ahead and create a designated dao for each model in your app, or look at some of the other data access design patterns: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/. See the part about object relational mapping patterns.

Comment: also, why delete the follow-up question explaining about you're database setup?

Comment: I beg your pardon but i deleted just for SO neatness no further question in a ques or comment.